# rails 4 ActionController::UrlGenerationError no match route with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am currently using rspec for unit test, I have traveled quite a doc and I did not find the answer.
I think I just used.
when I test my controller it tells me that is not my way and yet when I test in normal mode so everything works my way to work.

here Controller

```
#app/controller/app/email_contacts_controller.rb
class App::EmailContactsController < App::ApplicationController
  def create
  end
end
```

here rspec controller

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe App::EmailContactsController, type: :controller do
  login_lawyer_partner

  let(:contact) { create(:contact) }
  let(:lawyer) { controller.current_user }
  let(:order) { create :order, contact_id: contact.id, lawyer_id: lawyer.id}

  describe 'POST email_contacts' do
    before :each do
     xhr :post :create, id: order.id, mail: { subject: 'Mail Subject', reply_to:    'toto titi <tooto@titi.com', message: 'This is a long message which length has to be greater than seventy characters, so it passes' }
    order.reload
  end

  it { expect(Order.all).to eq [order] }
  it { is_expected.to respond_with :success }
  it { expect(order.comments.count).to eq 1 }
 end
end
```

`puts params => "controller"=>"app/email_contacts", "action"=>"create"`

And 
`rake route`

`app_order_email_contacts_path  POST /app/orders/:order_id/email_contacts(.:format)  app/email_contacts#create`

Yet the url is working well, so I think I forgot something or keyword, but I do not see what could miss

Thank you

Comment: I found my mistake is in my resources and params set was order_id.

so I replaced it and id by order_id match

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have spotted the error. When using a xhr in controller tests there is a comma after the verb symbol. You are missing one after the :post.

Minimally rewritten:

```
xhr :post, :create, id: order.id, mail: { ...
```